# Collision Avoidance By Hiding Variables Inside a Function Scope

Tags: javascript, scope

Im unable to wrap my head around this code snippet which explains how collision takes place between variables .

```js
function foo() {
  function bar(a) {
    i = 3;
    
    console.log(a+i);
  }
  
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    bar(i+2);
  }
  
}

foo();
```

This code tends to create an infinite loop due to collision of variables. Declaring " var i = 3" solves the problem but how do i utilize the scope to "hide" the inner declaration of the variable i ? And mainly why does the infinite loop problem arrive in the first place?

However, when I remove the assignment of "i = 3", would that be considered as a solution to the problem?

```js
function foo() {
  function bar(a) {
    console.log(a+i); 
  }
  
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    bar(i+2);
  }
 
}

foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do i utilize the scope to "hide" the inner declaration of the variable

There is no inner **declaration** of the variable.

Inside `bar` you *assign a new value to `i`* **without** declaring (via `const`, `let` or the old `var`, or sideways with a `function` declaration) a new `i`. This means you overwrite the existing value of `i`.

> And mainly why does the infinite loop problem arrive in the first place?

- The loop stops when `i` is no longer less than ten.
- Every time you go around the loop `bar` sets `i` back to `3`

Therefore `i` never gets to 11.

Comment: I even tried using another variable name declaration ( var j = 3 ) , the output changes completely than what was expected .